# How to change the Hex dump of a process in C

Tags: c, hex, dump

i wrote this code to change the hex dump of a selected process, here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
unsigned char buffer[5];
int i;
unsigned char patchbytes[5] = { 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC};

DWORD pid = atoi(argv[1]);

HANDLE hproc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

if (!hproc)
{
    printf("open failed\n");
    return -1;
}

ReadProcessMemory(hproc, (void*)0x77992FF5, buffer, 5, NULL);

printf("Before:\n");
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(patchbytes); i++) {

    printf("%02x \t", buffer[i]);

}

printf("\n");
WriteProcessMemory(hproc, (void*)0x77992FF5, patchbytes, 5, NULL);

printf("After:\n");
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(patchbytes); i++) {

    printf("%02x \t", buffer[i]);

}

FlushInstructionCache(hproc, NULL, 0);

CloseHandle(hproc);

return 0;

}
```

so i read the first five bytes, then i write over it, i check the values of the bytes before and after overwriting them. but it is giving me the same so the bytes did not change. what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Time to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). When do you read the *changed* memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply print the initially read buffer twice.

Toss in another `ReadProcessMemory(hproc, (void*)0x77992FF5, buffer, 5, NULL);` after `WriteProcessMemory`.